# CSS Three Tone Diagonal Background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 3 color background with colors going diagonally.

I found a great example with colors i like here: [Responsive Diagonal Two-Tone Backgrounds with CSS (Corner to Corner)](https://joshuawinn.com/responsive-diagonal-two-color-backgrounds-with-css/)

```css
.btn {
  background:#212531;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #2f3441 50%, #212531 50%);
  
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0.75em 2.0em;
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0.25em 0;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  background:#2d3d64;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #415382 50%, #2d3d64 50%);
}



body { text-align:center; background:#e6e9f6; padding-top:1.0em; }
a { text-decoration:none; }
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#">Check Out My Background</a>
```

I want to modify this example to have a third color, going from the bottom left corner, diagonally up to the middle of the screen and then stopping there.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below. Simply consider an extra gradient with a diagonal direction.

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 50%,yellow 50.5%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,red         50%,blue   50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: That would be perfect. Im just trying to modify it to get the red to be 45deg top right corner to bottom left corner. And have the yellow 45deg bottom left corner to middle

Comment: @CodyPritchard change the values of direction, you can combine `top/bottom` and `left/right` like you want to have the needed result

Comment: @CodyPritchard in this case switch the left with and right and right with left

Answer (score 0):

According to this example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

You can use something like that:

```
background: linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
```